# Reading multiple CSV files to plot multiple curves on same graph with Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, graph, cycle

I run several numerical computations and the results of each computation are stored in a .csv file. Lets say data1.csv, data2.csv, data3.csv, .etc that are composed of 4 columns.
I would like to read column 2 and 4 of several csv files and plot the curves presenting column 4 as a function of column 2 of the same graph to compare numerical computations.

I currently succeed in plotting 1 curve but not to automatize the procedure for n .csv file.

Here is my code :

```
x = []
y = []
path='/ref_path/'
calcul_id='ref_computation/'
file='data1.csv'
file_in=path+calcul_id+file
with open(file_in,'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[1]))
        y.append(float(row[3]))
  
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: you could just read each file in individually (just make a function out of your reading in and adding the points to the lists) or you could read them each in at the same time (though you would have to make sure that the files are the same length otherwise you may not get all of the csv content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you want to do is to iterate over the folder containing all your csv files. You can use the glob module, which is a part of Python standard library.

Your code will look something like this :

```
import glob
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

directory_countaining_csv_files = '...'

number_of_files = len(glob.glob(f'{directory_countaining_csv_files}/data*.csv'))

for filepath in glob.iglob(f'{directory_countaining_csv_files}/data*.csv'):
    x = []
    y = []
    with open(filepath,'r') as csvfile:
        plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for row in plots:
            x.append(float(row[1]))
            y.append(float(row[3]))

    plt.plot(x, y, label=f'{filepath}')

#Get labels from legends 
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

#specify order of items in legend
order = [i for i in range(number_of_files)]

plt.legend([handles[idx] for idx in order],[labels[idx] for idx in order]) 

plt.show()
```

The argument 'directory_countaining_files/data*.csv' will make sure that glob.iglob will return every csv file that starts with "data". I advise you to take a look at python documentation : https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/glob.html

I added a way to order legends in the final plot, i found the idea from this example : https://www.statology.org/matplotlib-legend-order/ .

This implementation can be awkward, 2 other ways to do it would be :

1. Sort files inside your folder by hand.
2. Use glob.glob() instead of glob.iglob().

glob.glob() will return a list of csv files in your directory. You can sort this list and iterate over it, the rest of the code will be the same.

```
list_csv = glob.glob(f'{directory_countaining_csv_files}/data*.csv')
list_csv.sort()

for file in liste_csv:
   x=[]
   y=[]
    ... same code as before ...
```

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is that the order in the legend box does not follow alphabetic order : I have data1.csv, data2.csv, data5.csv, data3.csv, data4.csv. Is it possible to reorder the curve ?

Comment: I edited my answer to take this into consideration.